# Adding a fee to WooCommerce product variation passed to cart

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, cart, price, product-variations

I am trying to add a fee (20$) to a product when I add it to the cart.

My function works when the product is a simple product. But not when it is a variation product. I have tried the following code, which throws a eval()'d code error on line 6:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );
function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {    
    $product_simple = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $product_var = wc_get_product( $variation_id ); 
    $price_simple = $product_simple->get_price();
    $price_var = $product_var->get_price(); 

    if ( $price_simple !== $price_var ) {
        $price = $price_var;
    } else {
        $price = $price_simple;
    }   
    if( ! empty( $_POST['custom_text_add_on'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['new_price'] = $price + 20;
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you LoicThe Aztec! Your code works perfectly for variable products. But my problem is not solved: the fee can be added either to a simple product or to a variable one. Your code alas does not cover the simple product case. So I have code that works when a simple product added to the cart. I also have code, thanks to you, that works when a variable product is added to the cart. But not code that works in both cases!

Comment: Sorry, stupid of me. I simply added on top of your code a filter with a function "define_simple_price_with_fee", exact copy of your code but with $product_id instead of $variation_id, and it works! I would have thought that the two consecutive "return $cart_item_data;" would clash, but they return the proper value! Thank you again LoicTheAztec, popcorn is coming ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code and some missing functions… To add a fee to each product variation in cart, try the following instead:

```php
// Define variation price with fee
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'define_variation_price_with_fee', 10, 3 );
function define_variation_price_with_fee( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {   
    // Only for product variations
    if ( $variation_id > 0 ) {
        // Define the fee amount to be added
        $variation_fee = 20; 
        // Get an instance of the product variation object
        $variation     = wc_get_product( $variation_id ); 
        // Add price with fee as custom cart item data
        $cart_item_data['price_with_fee'] = $variation->get_price() + $variation_fee;
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}


// Display variation price with fee html (cart, mini-cart and checkout)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'display_variation_price_with_fee', 10, 2 );
function display_variation_price_with_fee($price, $cart_item) {
    // Check item for the price with fee
    if ( isset($cart_item['price_with_fee']) ) {
        // Set the price with fee in arguments
        $args = array('price' => floatval($cart_item['price_with_fee']));

        if ('incl' === get_option('woocommerce_tax_display_cart')) {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_including_tax($cart_item['data'], $args);
        } else {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax($cart_item['data'], $args);
        }
        return wc_price($product_price);
    }
    return $price;
}

// Set variation price with fee (when order is submitted)
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' , 'set_variation_price_with_fee' );
function set_variation_price_with_fee( $cart ) { 
    if ( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        // Check items for the price with fee
        if ( isset($item['price_with_fee']) ) {
            // Set the price with fee
            $item['data']->set_price($item['price_with_fee']);
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.